# Run Github Action only when a push to main comes from a branch with a certain name

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github Action that deploys my app from the main branch when there is a push to it or a merge from a pull request:

```
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to only run the action if the pull request comes from a branch that does not contain the string "nodeploy/" in its name.

I tried this:

```
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    if: ${{ !startsWith(github.head_ref, 'nodeploy/') }}
```

but it didn't work.

I believe it doesn't work because the value of `github.head_ref` is always `main` in this case.

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question as asked, but maybe you could use a flag in the commit message itself? Say, if "nodeploy" occurs in the commit log, don't deploy? Since the default merge message says what branch is merged in, this solution can be almost automatic from the branch name, as long as you make sure not to edit that part of the commit message out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. As suggested in the comments, I checked the message in the head commit.

```
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    if: ${{ !contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'nodeploy/') }}
```

And now it does what I wanted.

Be aware that if you change the automatically generated merge message it won't work.